# page redirect automatic in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

i call method of controller using ajax but page redirect to same page my controller and ajax code is as below

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
   echo "In store method";
   die();
 }
```

ajax code

```
$('document').ready(function () {
        $("#add-to-cart").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '{{ route('stock_sell.store') }}',
                data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
                success:{

                }
            })
        });
});
```

use resource route so i think, it doesnl't issue with route. i used `die()` but it also doesn't work, automaric redirect to `stock_sell.index` from where was i.

Comment: This is an issue with jQuery, not with Laravel, I suggest that you change your tags if you want to get more relevant help.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably `#add-to-cart` is a link, in which case you need to use JavaScript to prevent the click event from continuing to load the link's href. You can do this using `e.preventDefault()`:-

```
$("#add-to-cart").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '{{ route('stock_sell.store') }}',
        data: { "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
        success:{

        }
    })
});
```

You can always check what is actually happening by opening your browser's dev tools and looking at the Network tab. If you enable the 'Preserve log' option you can see exactly what resources are getting loaded and what they are returning; so you should be able to see the AJAX call.

Comment: @user3649115 did you check with the browsers dev tools to see what is happening when you click on `#add-to-cart`?

Comment: sure, it print value `In store method` and then automatic redirect to page

Comment: @user3649115 in which case it sounds like `e.preventDefault()` isn't working. Make sure you pass the parameter `e` in the click callback function as shown in my answer. You can also ensure the callback function returns `false` to prevent the link from loading the new URL. Try adding some breakpoints to your JS in the dev tools and checking where the redirect occurs.

Comment: while i add `e.preventDefault()` then it stop to redirect on any method so, i remove it.

Comment: @user3649115 you should only be applying `e.preventDefault()` to the click event that triggers your AJAX call. If it is affecting all links then it would imply your jQuery selector isn't right. If you don't want your link to reload/redirect then you must disable is default behaviour which is why you would use `preventDefault`.